# How to import a package given full path?

Tags: python, python-3.5, python-importlib

My question is similar to [How to import a module given the full path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path) however I'm not importing a .py source file, I'm importing a package with a .pyd.

During runtime I am creating new package modules from some dynamically generated c code. I successfully generate package Foo with a `__init__.py` file and a `mod.pyd`:

```
/a/temp/dir/foo/
    __init__.py
    bar.pyd
```

The example code I'm working with is

```
import importlib.util
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location("foo.bar", "/path/to/file.py")
foo = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(foo)
foo.bar()
```

If I attempt to use `spec_from_file_location('foo.bar', '/a/temp/dir/foo/__init__.py')` the module `bar` from the pyd fails to load.

If I attempt to use `spec_from_file_location('foo.bar', '/a/temp/dir/foo/')` then `spec_from_file_location` returns `None`.

If I attempt to use `spec_from_file_location('foo.bar', '/a/temp/dir/foo/bar.pyd')` I get the following error stack:

```
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 903, in create_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
```

An alternative to the recommended 4 line importlib solution is to create concrete classes for `MetaPathFinder` and `SourceLoader`. My following `MetaPathFinder` works fine, however, I am unsure how to implement the `Loader` correctly. `get_data` return value expects some Unicode representation of python code. How do I return the package structure or the pyd contents in the loader?

```
class MyLoader(importlib.abc.SourceLoader):
    def __init__(self, fullname, path, pyd):
        self.path = path
        self.fullname = fullname
        self.pyd = pyd

    def get_data(self, path):
        print('*** get_data', path)
        with open(os.path.join(self.path, self.pyd), 'r') as f:
            return f.read()

    def get_filename(self, fullname):
        print('*** get_filename', fullname)
        return os.path.join(self.path, '__init__.py')

    def is_package(self):
        return True

class MyFinder(MetaPathFinder):
    def __init__(self, this_module, workdir, pyd):
        self._this_module = this_module
        self._workdir = workdir
        self._pyd = pyd

    def find_spec(self, fullname, path, target=None):
        print('find_spec', fullname, path, target, self._this_module)

        if fullname != self._this_module:
            return

        filename = os.path.join(self._workdir, self._this_module)

        spec = ModuleSpec(
            name = fullname,
            loader = MyLoader(fullname, filename, self._pyd),
            origin = filename,
            loader_state = 1234,
            is_package = True,
        )
        return spec

    def is_package(self):
        return True
```